# How to reorder table rows using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table similar to the following: 
    Level 
        $1,000 
        $500 
        $100 
        Other Amount 
The HTML is generated by a web based program that allows you to enter your desired values but does not  provide an option to re-order them.

The values are ordered highest to lowest but I need them to be lowest to highest.

Here is the HTML that produced the table:

```
<table width="100%" id="TablePledgeLevelInner">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Level<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="Radio1" onclick="SetAmount(form, 1000);" value="764853" name="PledgeLevelID">&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>$1,000&nbsp;<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="Radio1" onclick="SetAmount(form, 500);" value="764915" name="PledgeLevelID">&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>$500&nbsp;<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="Radio1" onclick="SetAmount(form, 100);" value="764921" name="PledgeLevelID">&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>$100&nbsp;<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="Radio1" onclick="SetAmount(form, 0);" value="764922" name="PledgeLevelID">&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>Other Amount&nbsp;<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How would I reorder this table using Jquery or Javascript?
Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net/). It'll let you sort the output and provide loads of other nice functionality out of the box.